# Login only works for first data in database?

Tags: php

This is my login.php page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$f_usr= $_POST["username"];
$f_pswd= $_POST["password"];

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(! $con)
{
        die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("login",$con);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row["username"]==$f_usr && $row["password"]==$f_pswd)
    {
        echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
        echo "alert('Successfully Log In');\n";
        echo "window.location='MainPage.html'";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
        echo "alert('Username or Password was incorrect!');\n";
        echo "window.location='login.html'";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my register.php page

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','login');

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
        echo 'Failed to connect';
}

?>

<?php

// create a variable
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

//Execute the query

mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO data(username, password)
                VALUES('$username','$password')");

            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
                echo "alert('Successfully Register');\n";
                echo "window.location='MainPage.html'";
                echo "</script>";
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
                echo "alert('Failed to Register');\n";
                echo "window.location='Register.html'";
                echo "</script>";
            }

?>
```

Here's my problem. I using xammp and I have 3 data currently iin my database. Wheni try to log in with my first data in databse it works, but when i try to log in with the 2nd data in databse it show incorrect  username and password? Why?

Comment: You don't have a where clause in your query.

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM data Where username='ddd' AND password='dddd'"` and use PDO to avoid sql injections

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the following lines,

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ...
```

You're getting the entire result set with `mysql_query()`, and you're fetching **only** the first row from the result set. And that's why when you try to login with first data it works, but when you try to login with second or third data it doesn't work.

So **the solution** is,

Make your query like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = '$f_usr' LIMIT 1");
```

It will return a result set comprising of a single row *if it exists*. And then fetch the row without any `while` loop, like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // your code
}else{
    // Incorrect username
}
```

---

**Sidenotes:**

- Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).
- Your queries are susceptible to SQL injection. Always **prepare**, **bind** and **execute** your queries to prevent any kind of SQL injection. [And this is how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
- Never store password as a plain readable text, always perform [salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on raw password before inserting it into the table.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So the column `password` need not to be wrapped in backticks? Would it work?

Comment: That is correct - columns named after keywords do not need to have the back ticking.

Comment: ...unless they are used as a function. It's rare but it happens. If so, then it needs to be ticked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so it means that if a function or a procedure is named as `password` then it should be ticked, and if it's used as table name or column name then it need not to be ticked, am I getting this right?

Comment: pretty much @RajdeepPaul yes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the clarification. Learnt few things today. :-)